# How to rename woocommerce-billing-fields

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, html

I'm interested in how you could rename the "billing & shipping" and "your order" fields marked in the image.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It depends on the code. We are unaware of the theme that you are using. But I feel this will be in one of the checkout files. Copy them to the child theme and override the names.

Answer (score 1):

Copy

`\woocommerce\templates\checkout\form-billing.php`

and

`\woocommerce\templates\checkout\form-checkout.php`

to

`\yourtheme\woocommerce\checkout\form-billing.php`

find this code `<h3><?php _e( 'Billing & Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>` in `form-billing.php` and `<h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php esc_html_e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>`

and make the necessary changes .

Hope you are not doing this for anything regarding to I18n.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my problem.

Comment: @MarkoPopovic If it solved your problem please accept the answer .